# Is there a neater or alternative way of saying "fully qualified"?

Tags: resume

I'm a consultant who focuses on a particular vendor's technology. I've worked very hard to pass every single exam that the vendor publishes, and I'd like to show this off without sounding too cocky.

"Fully qualified" doesn't seem to have quite the right feel to it and feels more like a euphemism to say, "I have enough qualifications," rather than "I have all the qualifications."

Am I over thinking this? Is there an alternative phrase I could use?

Comment: Yes, you're overthinking this.  Fully Qualified is fine.  Now go get the job.

Comment: Picking nits, here, but I would use "Fully certified" in this instance.  Certifications are specific.  Qualified is, in some cases, subjective.  Local cultural influences may color this, too.

Answer (score 4):

**Show, don't tell.**

Include something like "Have passed all exams in series" in your resume. further demonstrate your familiarities with the technology by talking about problems you've solved or things you've built using that technology. It's up to them to judge whether you're fully qualified, and they'll do that based on the information they receive about you.